# Configuring behaviour of touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I have a laptop that includes a touchpad. The bottom ~10cm of the pad is marked for left/right buttons, and that section of the pad is hinged so that it can click.

I've run into two problems:

1) When resting a finger(s) on the left or right "buttons", the rest of the pad is unresponsive

2) There seems to be no way to trigger a "left and right" click - useful for pasting

I've been looking at ways of changing the behaviour of the pad to, ideally, allow for both of the above to work. I know point 1) works when I boot the same machine into windows...any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Askubuntu. Can you please let us know your laptop make and model? Also the version of Ubuntu you're running.

Comment: Doesn't your right click button bring up a contextual menu that includes `copy` and `paste`?

Comment: In answer to the first query: Lenovo ideapad 510s

Comment: In answer to the second, yes I can use the context menu - but double click paste is handy if it can be achieved. I downloaded a touchpad manager from the repository that seemed to allow for some configuration, but its settings (including disable touchpad) seem to have no effect